# Devise sign_out by email instead of authenticity in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I am implementing Devise in rails.
I am new to ruby-on-rails and devise.

For this I am using Devise-3.24, Ruby 1.9.3, and Rails-4.0
I have added devise on Customer model. Creating customer, sign_in customer working fine.

Sign-out function taking 'authenticity_token' as request parameter. But I want to sign_out customer by email_id or 'access_token'.
I want to pass email or access_token to sign-out from the devise.

Is there any way to get either "authenticity_token" in mycontroller or to pass different parameter to sign_out devise?

My routes.rb is -

```
devise_for :customers, :controllers => {:sessions => "sessions", :passwords => "passwords"}
```

My customer model -

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :lockable
end
```

I want to either return "authenticity_token" in the response of sign_customer to the webservice client or I want to sign_out customer by email or other parameter.
How can achieve this?

Comment: why do you want to that? any problem with the existing functionality?

Comment: We have developed webservices in RoR and we are calling these webservices from PHP client, so we want to return the authenticity_token in the response of sign_in, so that PHP client can send the this token for sign_out webservice